# Would it be possible to create a bleeding wall/object effect in blender?

Tags: modeling, particles, fluid-simulation

I'd like to create a fluid animation of blood/dye running down a wall something like the effect they have on the music video 'Dean - Instagram' however It seems like the effect in the video is actually just pictures being dragged down in each frame, would it be possible to simulate a more accurate liquid animation in  blender? and how would I go about doing so?

Comment: Did you inform yourself (e.g. watch tutorials)? If so, can you please be more precise, what your ideas are? Stackexchange is probably not the platform to get a whole scene done by someone.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add images that exemplify what you want to do ( to learn how to post images [read this link:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)).